Converting 3ds/obj/fbx 3d model to glb
Im trying to implement a 3d baseball stadium model to my next.js project using three.js/r3f.
The problem is that the model i need only supports fbx, 3ds, obj format, and as far as i know, to implement the model as i pretended, it has to be a glb format file.
Will there be any major issues when converting fbx, 3ds, obj file to glb? If not which one will be the best choice to convert to a glb file? I already converted and previewed free models on three.js editor and all three seem to crash a bit.
And fyi, the model that i want most doesn't support fbx.
I tried to find some information regarding this, but couldn't really find an answer. The model costs quite a lot so i want to make sure.


The problem is that the model i need only supports fbx, 3ds, obj
format, and as far as i know, to implement the model as i pretended,
it has to be a glb format file.

No, it doesn't have to be glb/gltf. This format is recommended but not the only one, both in Three.js and R3F. You can successfully use obj or fbx etc.
https://docs.pmnd.rs/react-three-fiber/tutorials/loading-models
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/examples/models
